# SQlite Unique Key not working

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm using a local SQlite database and created some unique keys. All of them are working as expected except for one. 
The table is for storing city information. Therefore the columns Name, Nation, Region and PostalCode have to be unique.
That said it should never be possible to add the same entry twice (except for the primary key).

In VS2012 (using the sqlite designer) I can copy a whole row, and paste in new (changing one element of the PK) and the whole new set is stored without any error.

Other tables with UKs set do throw errors if I try the same.

So what can cause this error?

Note: All parts of the UK are nvarchar-values. Maybe this is a point to start with. Other tables I checked do always have Guid as part of their UK.

**Edit:**

[image]

**Edit:**

Also tried to set the following:

- CityName - nvarchar(200)
- CityPostalCode - nvarchar(50),
- CityRegion - nvarchar(150) and
- CityCountry - varchar(5)

but still the same

Comment: Show the table structure.

Comment: What fields are part of the UK?

Comment: CityName, CityPostalCode, CityRegion and CityCountry